# NSNotification Observer Closure not removed when Observer is removed?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in a view controller to register for one of my custom notifications. I have used the selectors until now for registering but thought I would try the closures instead and noticed something weird.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "notificationReceived:", name: "NotificationKey", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("NotificationKey", object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
    NSLog("Notification received in closure!")
}

@objc private func notificationReceived(notification: NSNotification) {
    NSLog("Notification received!")
}
```

I then remove the view controller as an observer.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

Once the observer is removed, I still see the NSLog in the Closure, but I don't see the NSLog in the selector function. It appears the closure is being held onto by the notification center. I've also noticed the closure can cause a retain cycle if self is referenced within it (adding [weak self] fixes this, but the NSLog line is still called).

Does anyone know why the closure is still handling the notification?

Would there ever be a case where you would use the closure over the selector (I prefer them because it avoids magic strings)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`addObserverForName(_:object:queue:usingBlock:)` actually **returns an object** that you can hold onto. It's this object which you should pass to `removeObserver()`.

```
var observer: AnyObject?

// ...

observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Class.notificationName, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
    NSLog("Notification received in closure!")
}

// ...

if let observer = observer {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
}
```

Comment: Minor correction: you'll have to unwrap `observer` before passing it to `removeObserver(_:)` since you declared it as optional.

Comment: Ah, duh. Didn't see it returned something. Thanks! I can convert my selectors now! (I hate selectors :P)